My function sched_init don't do what i want
I need to make a LIFO scheduler in C using pthread.
The LIFO scheduler contains a single stack of tasks whose maximum size is given by the
parameter passed to sched_init. Initially, the stack contains only the initial task. When a
thread has nothing to do, it unstacks a task from the stack and performs it; if there are no tasks ready
the thread goes to sleep waiting for one (for example, the sched_spawn function can
try to wake up a thread). When a new task is created, it is stacked on the stack.
The scheduler terminates when the stack is empty and all threads are asleep.
You'll notice that the stack is a shared structure, so you'll need to protect it with synchronization pri- mitives.
mitives. You'll also need to use synchronization primitives to wake up any
and terminate them when the scheduler become idle.
That's my file.h:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct scheduler;

typedef void (*taskfunc)(void*, struct scheduler *);

// Structure pour une tâche
typedef struct {
    taskfunc task;
    void *closure;
} Task;

typedef struct scheduler
{
  Task *tasks;
  int qlen;
  int nthreads;
  int size;
  pthread_t *threads;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex; // Mutex pour la synchronisation
  pthread_cond_t condition; // Condition pour attendre les tâches
} scheduler;

static inline int
sched_default_threads()
{
    return sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
}

int sched_init(int nthreads, int qlen, taskfunc f, void *closure);
int sched_spawn(taskfunc f, void *closure, struct scheduler *s);


#include "sched.h"

/*************************************************/
/*                                               */
/*                sucre syntaxique               */
/*                                               */
/*************************************************/

#define AND &&
#define OR ||
#define ISNOT !=
#define NOT !
#define then

typedef enum { FALSE, TRUE} bool;

/*************************************************/
/*                                               */
/*                predeclarations                */
/*                                               */
/*************************************************/

/* initialise un struct scheduler vide */
void initVide(struct scheduler *L);

/* renvoie 1 si le struct scheduler en parametre est vide, 0 sinon */
bool estVide(struct scheduler *L);

/* renvoie le premier element du struct scheduler en parametre */
taskfunc premier(struct scheduler *L);

/* renvoie un nouveau struct scheduler correspondant a celui en parametre, avec l'element task ajoute en haut de la pile */
struct scheduler ajoute(taskfunc task, void *closure, struct scheduler *L);

/* modifie le struct scheduler en parametre: task est ajoute comme premier element */
void empile(taskfunc task, void *closure, struct scheduler* L);

/* modifie le struct scheduler en parametre: le premier element est retire */
void depile(struct scheduler* L);

/* affichage simple du struct scheduler */
void affiche(struct scheduler *L);
/* longueur en recursif et en iteratif */
int longueur (struct scheduler *L);

/*************************************************/
/*                                               */
/*                briques de base                */
/*                                               */
/*************************************************/

void initVide(struct scheduler *L) {
    L->tasks = NULL;
    L->qlen = 0;
    L->nthreads = 0;
    L->size = 0;
    L->threads = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&(L->mutex), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(L->condition), NULL);
}

bool estVide(struct scheduler *L) {
    return L->size == 0;
}

taskfunc premier(struct scheduler *L) {
    if (estVide(L)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur : le struct scheduler est vide.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return L->tasks[0].task;
}

struct scheduler ajoute(taskfunc task, void *closure, struct scheduler *L) {
    Task newTask = {task, closure};
    if (L->size >= L->qlen) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur : le scheduler est plein.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    L->tasks[L->size++] = newTask;
    return *L;
}

void empile(taskfunc task, void *closure, struct scheduler *L)
{
  ajoute(task, closure, L) ;
}

void depile(struct scheduler *L) {
    if (estVide(L)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur : le struct scheduler est vide.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(L->tasks[L->size - 1].closure); // Libère la mémoire de la tâche retirée
    L->size--; // Réduit la taille du struct scheduler
}

/*************************************************/
/*                                               */
/*     Affiche, avec les briques de base         */
/*                                               */
/*************************************************/

void affiche(struct scheduler *L) {
    for (int i = 0; i < L->size; i++) {
        printf("%p ", L->tasks[i].task);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/*************************************************/
/*                                               */
/*     Longueur, sans les briques de base        */
/*                                               */
/*************************************************/

int longueur (struct scheduler *L)
{
    return L -> size;
}

/*************************************************/
/*                                               */
/*       Libere la memoire                       */
/*                                               */
/*************************************************/

void VideScheduler(struct scheduler *L)
{
  if(NOT(estVide(L)))
  {
    depile(L);
    VideScheduler(L);
  }

}

// Fonction de tâche simple qui affiche un message
void *task_function(void *arg) {
    char *message = (char *)arg;
    printf("Thread %lu executing task: %s\n", pthread_self(), message);
    sleep(1); // Simulation d'une tâche longue
    return NULL;
}

int sched_init(int nthreads, int qlen, taskfunc f, void *closure) {
    // Faut initialiser notre ordonnanceur et créez les threads si nécessaire
    // Il faut également initialiser la pile de tâches avec la tâche initiale
    struct scheduler *scheduler = (struct scheduler *)malloc(sizeof(struct scheduler));
    if (scheduler == NULL) {
        perror("Erreur lors de l'allocation du struct scheduler");
        return -1;
    }
    scheduler->nthreads = (nthreads == 0) ? sched_default_threads() : nthreads;
    scheduler->qlen = qlen;
    scheduler->tasks = (Task *)malloc(qlen * sizeof(Task));
    if (scheduler->tasks == NULL) {
        perror("Erreur lors de l'allocation de la mémoire pour les tâches");
        free(scheduler);
        return -1;
    }

    // Ajout de la tâche initiale au tableau de tâches
    scheduler->tasks[0].task = f;
    scheduler->tasks[0].closure = closure;
    scheduler->size++;

    // Vérification si la taille du tableau est suffisante pour le nombre de threads à créer
    if (scheduler->nthreads > qlen) {
        printf("Ajustement du nombre de threads au maximum de la capacité du tableau de tâches.\n");
        scheduler->nthreads = qlen;
    }
    // Création des threads
    scheduler->threads = (pthread_t *)malloc(scheduler->nthreads * sizeof(pthread_t));
    if (scheduler->threads == NULL) {
        perror("Erreur lors de l'allocation de la mémoire pour les threads");
        free(scheduler->tasks);
        free(scheduler);
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < scheduler->nthreads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&(scheduler->threads[i]), NULL,(void *(*)(void *))f, closure);
    }

    // Ajout de la tâche initiale
    empile(f, closure, scheduler);

    // Attente de la fin des threads
    for (int i = 1; i < scheduler->nthreads; i++) {
        pthread_join(scheduler->threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;

}

int sched_spawn(taskfunc f, void *closure, struct scheduler *s) {
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    char *message = "Task1";
    // Initialisation du scheduler avec 2 threads et une longueur de file de 5
    int result = sched_init(0, 4, task_function, (void*) message); // Initialisation du scheduler
    if (result != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur lors de l'initialisation du scheduler\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


I've tried to do this as a first test but I think I'm off-topic. Could you please tell me if I'm in agreement with what I've explained in the statement?
I'd like to point out that I have an appendix file that implements the quicksort and serves as an example where I need to use my LIFO scheduler to execute the quicksort and see how long it took to do the quicksort.

Is there a question here?  You have some "scheduler" data structures that you put some stuff into, but you never use them for anything -- you just run some pthread threads (using the pthread scheduler) that print some messages.  What are you trying to do?  If this is homework, what do you not understand about the problem statement?
